# FirebaseCrashlytics/run: No such file or directory error while building the app - swift

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am integrating the Firebase Analytics and the Crashlytics in my app. After Initializing the Crashlytics, I am getting the following error while building the app.

mediates.noindex/AppName.build/Release-iphoneos/AppName.build/Script-CEF6C7C8235DEDE800229776.sh: line 3: /Users/apple/Documents/AppFolder/AppName/Folder/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/run: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

The following is my transcript configuration
I have imported the crashlytics pod and analytics pod. How to fix this issue. Any help is really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the steps you've taken so far for the Crashlytics integration based on what's here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios. And if you enable debug mode (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#enable_debug_logging), you may get more logs. If so, please post those as well.

Answer (score 93):

If you installed `firebase` using `cocoa pods` use:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

If you installed `firebase` using  `Swift Package Manager` use:

```
"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"
```

Comment: Why this doesn't make it into Firebase documentation is beyond me.

Comment: @liquid Yeah, This is very critical!! Firebase docs should be updated!!

Comment: it's written here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

Comment: @Philip Mintah -  thank you for your answer. I am looking up for this more than an hour. Anyone having this issue https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods - Here you can find the link.

Comment: Saved my day! thanks a lot <3 again another great! firebase documentation issue...

Comment: Here is the update link of Firebase Docs (to know what to use if you're using SwiftPackageManager or CocoaPods): https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#analytics-not-enabled

Answer (score 15):

It helped me.
Check your `podfile`, it should contain the following:

```
# Add the pod for Firebase Crashlytics
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
# Recommended: Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

and run `pod install`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

> To continue getting crash reports in the
> Firebase console, make sure you upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics
> SDK versions 17.0.0+ for Android, 4.0.0+ for iOS, and 6.15.0+ for
> Unity.

Comment: It didn't work in my case

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71370116/1138498) by Philip Mintah, if you are using ***Swift Package Manager*** you should use a different path to `Crashlytics`, another thing worth to mention is that you are probably using *upload-symbols* script which also requires a path change.

So if you are using ***CocoaPods***:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

If you are using ***Swift Package Manager***:

```
${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

Hope that helps!