# firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run: No such file or directory

Tags: swift, objective-c, firebase, macos, crashlytics

I have a problem everytime I archive for any mac (catalyst)

here is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9YXB.png)

and also this is my build phase -> Crashlytics run script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmm54.png)

can anyone help me with this ? thank you

I've done the suggestions I get from this thread.
[FirebaseCrashlytics/run: No such file or directory error while building the app - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63704911/firebasecrashlytics-run-no-such-file-or-directory-error-while-building-the-app)

but the same error still exists