# Firebase automate uploading dsyms - Swift package manager

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, swift-package-manager, dsym

We have added dependencies via SPM. Can we automate uploading dsyms with this configuration or we have to add the Firebase package using Cocoapods or Carthage.

This is my script for uploading symbols when firebase sdk is added via SPM and it doesn't work

```
googleServiceFileName="GoogleService-Info"

echo "Symbols Directory"
echo "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"


"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run" -gsp
 "${PROJECT_DIR}/project/GoogleServicesInfo/${googleServiceFileName}.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Comment: The question isn't clear; what does - *doesn't work* - mean specifically? The Firebase guide to set up Crashlytics [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) has a specific section on setting up XCode (after using SPM) to [Automatically upload dsyms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading). Can you clarify the question and let us know what step in the setup guide isn't working? Then we can take a look and perhaps provide direction.

Comment: It is not not uploading dsyms to firebase console and I have to do it manually

Comment: There's just not enough info in the question; you may have forgotten, for example, to update the Input Files section or perhaps there's a typo. I suggest going through the getting started guide linked in my prior comment, and verify every step was followed. Then update the question with that info which will narrow down the cause.

Comment: Have you tried to change run command to upload-symbols because the run command is used to run the FirebaseCrashlytics framework in your app. The upload-symbols command is used to upload the dSYM file to Firebase Crashlytics.

also to if you get  lost in finding the right path:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63704911/firebasecrashlytics-run-no-such-file-or-directory-error-while-building-the-app

Answer (score 1):

Following [this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#swiftui) by Google, you should do the following:

1. Go to your project's build settings and search for `debug information format`, and set all build types to `DWARF with dSYM File`.
2. Add a new Run Script phase and add the following line:

```bash
"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"
```

3. Under "Input Files" add the following lines:

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${PRODUCT_NAME}
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Info.plist
$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/GoogleService-Info.plist
$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)
```

It should look something like this:
[image]

After every run it should upload the correct symbols to Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cocoapods to install firebase frameworks, try this:

```
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```